# Openbravo compilation failed

Tags: postgresql, ant, pgadmin, openbravo

I have a openbravo-3.0MP28.2.tar and trying to install it, when I coming to the step "ant install.source" I got the following exception:

```
[createdatabase] log4j:ERROR Could not instantiate class [org.openbravo.utils.OBLogAppender].
[createdatabase] java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.openbravo.utils.OBLogAppender
[createdatabase]        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
[createdatabase]        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
[createdatabase]        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
[createdatabase]        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
[createdatabase]        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
[createdatabase]        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
[createdatabase]        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
[createdatabase]        at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
[createdatabase]        at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:190)
[createdatabase]        at org.apache.log4j.helpers.Loader.loadClass(Loader.java:178)
[createdatabase]        at org.apache.log4j.helpers.OptionConverter.instantiateByClassName(OptionConverter.java:319)
[createdatabase]        at org.apache.log4j.helpers.OptionConverter.instantiateByKey(OptionConverter.java:120)
[createdatabase]        at org.apache.log4j.PropertyConfigurator.parseAppender(PropertyConfigurator.java:629)
[createdatabase]        at org.apache.log4j.PropertyConfigurator.parseCategory(PropertyConfigurator.java:612)
[createdatabase]        at org.apache.log4j.PropertyConfigurator.configureRootCategory(PropertyConfigurator.java:509)
[createdatabase]        at org.apache.log4j.PropertyConfigurator.doConfigure(PropertyConfigurator.java:415)
[createdatabase]        at org.apache.log4j.PropertyConfigurator.configure(PropertyConfigurator.java:349)
[createdatabase]        at org.openbravo.ddlutils.task.BaseDatabaseTask.initLogging(BaseDatabaseTask.java:79)
[createdatabase]        at org.openbravo.ddlutils.task.BaseDatabaseTask.execute(BaseDatabaseTask.java:85)
[createdatabase]        at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:288)
[createdatabase]        at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor1.invoke(Unknown Source)
[createdatabase]        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
[createdatabase]        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
[createdatabase]        at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
[createdatabase]        at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
[createdatabase]        at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.execute(Target.java:357)
[createdatabase]        at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.performTasks(Target.java:385)
[createdatabase]        at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeSortedTargets(Project.java:1337)
[createdatabase]        at org.apache.tools.ant.helper.SingleCheckExecutor.executeTargets(SingleCheckExecutor.java:38)
[createdatabase]        at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTargets(Project.java:1189)
[createdatabase]        at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Ant.execute(Ant.java:416)
[createdatabase]        at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.CallTarget.execute(CallTarget.java:105)
[createdatabase]        at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:288)
[createdatabase]        at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor1.invoke(Unknown Source)
[createdatabase]        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
[createdatabase]        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
[createdatabase]        at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
[createdatabase]        at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
[createdatabase]        at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.execute(Target.java:357)
[createdatabase]        at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.performTasks(Target.java:385)
[createdatabase]        at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeSortedTargets(Project.java:1337)
[createdatabase]        at org.apache.tools.ant.helper.SingleCheckExecutor.executeTargets(SingleCheckExecutor.java:38)
[createdatabase]        at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTargets(Project.java:1189)
[createdatabase]        at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Ant.execute(Ant.java:416)
[createdatabase]        at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:288)
[createdatabase]        at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor1.invoke(Unknown Source)
[createdatabase]        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
[createdatabase]        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
[createdatabase]        at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
[createdatabase]        at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
[createdatabase]        at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.execute(Target.java:357)
[createdatabase]        at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.performTasks(Target.java:385)
[createdatabase]        at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeSortedTargets(Project.java:1337)
[createdatabase]        at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTarget(Project.java:1306)
[createdatabase]        at org.apache.tools.ant.helper.DefaultExecutor.executeTargets(DefaultExecutor.java:41)
[createdatabase]        at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTargets(Project.java:1189)
[createdatabase]        at org.apache.tools.ant.Main.runBuild(Main.java:758)
[createdatabase]        at org.apache.tools.ant.Main.startAnt(Main.java:217)
[createdatabase]        at org.apache.tools.ant.launch.Launcher.run(Launcher.java:257)
[createdatabase]        at org.apache.tools.ant.launch.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:104)
[createdatabase] log4j:ERROR Could not instantiate appender named "A".
[createdatabase] log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.openbravo.ddlutils.task.CreateDatabase).
[createdatabase] log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
```

What am I doing wrong? 
my $CLASSPATH variable is empty, but nevertheless it is going ok when I compiling openbravo with empty global $CLASSPATH on diferent machine.

Answer (score 1):

This is not a platform problem, but probably a mistake in a particular Openbravo configuration. Following the steps described here

http://wiki.openbravo.com/wiki/How_to_setup_Eclipse_IDE

it is possible to successfully install, configure and use an Openbravo instance
(ur missing the jar file)